# insert data dynamically to html table with java

Tags: java, html, templates

I have template html file which look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
                  }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h2>Email Report: Crash in Log File</h2>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Device Mode</th>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Host Name</th>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Time</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="dm"></td>
            <td id="ip"></td>
            <td id="pla"></td>
            <td id="hn"></td>
            <td id="test"></td>
            <td id="time"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Stack Trace</th>
          
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="st"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have in my java porgram variables like ip, deviceName and etc and i want to insert these variables to the table

for exsample insert the ip var to `<td id="ip"></td>`

how can I do it ?

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to modify the template so you have something like `<td id="ip">${ip}</td>` or something similar, instead?

Comment: I can modify the template but I don't know how to insert vars in this way

Comment: My point is if it's ok for you to modify your template there's plenty of template engines you can use for such tasks. [Freemaker](https://freemarker.apache.org/), for example.